# Can't show custom post type in DK PDF converter

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf

I am working on a page with wordpress, I installed the plugin called DK PDF, which converts the page to a PDF so a visitor can download or print the page. The problem we have is that we can't convert a listing from a custom post type.

This is our code for the DK PDF template, where you manage what fields it shows:

```
    <html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" media="all" />
        <?php 
            $wp_head = get_option( 'dkpdf_print_wp_head', '' );
            if( $wp_head == 'on' ) {
                wp_head();
            } 
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background:#FFF;
                font-size: 100%;
            }
            <?php 
                $css = get_option( 'dkpdf_pdf_custom_css', '' );
                echo $css; 
            ?>          
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        global $post;
        $pdf  = get_query_var( 'pdf' );
        $post_type = get_post_type( $pdf );
      $args = array(
        'p' => $pdf,
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
      );               
      $the_query = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'dkpdf_query_args', $args ) );              
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {             
          while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
              $the_query->the_post();
              global $post; ?>



        <h1> <?php      
              the_title(); ?></h1>

         <?php      
              the_title(); 
              the_post_thumbnail();
              the_content();

              **THE ERROR:**

              /* The field with the error */
              <?= $woning->listing('woning.inhoud'); ?>

        ?>






          <?php }
        }    
        wp_reset_postdata();
      ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

So as you can see at the code close to the bottom that was the rule where we got an error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\vermunt\wp-content\themes\vermunt\dkpdf\dkpdf-index.php on line 48.

So my question is: how you do let these custom post types show in the template? Give some kind of buildup for the code or just rewrite the line :)

I don't have any experience with this, so it might be some stupid fault.

Thanks for helping in advance,

Yannick

Comment: Everything you need to know is in the error message - you have a **syntax error** so it is nothing to do with the plugin, it is to do with coding mistakes in your code. It even tells you where it is, so fix your code and it should work.

Comment: Nice help now I still don't know where the error comes from

Comment: Your php code is wrong on line 48....

Comment: Can you maybe make the line work for me? I really don't know :(